# How can I compile iOS in React Native Expo? (I use Apple Developer for free)

Tags: react-native, expo

I developed a project with React native expo and now I want to compile it with ios. Can't I do this for free? I tried it and it gives me this error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvVTI.png)

I was able to create an apk when I compiled it for Android, I want to do the same on iOS.

Comment: without apple developer account you can build for simulator only, add below "simulator":true on your eas.json build new development profile

{
    "build": {
      "preview": {
        "ios": {
          "simulator": true
        }
      },
      "developmentios": { "developmentClient": true, "distribution": "internal", "ios": { "simulator": true } },
      "production": {}
    }
  }
build command

eas build --profile developmentios --platform ios
reference: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/simulators/